# best alternative to cookie,when size limitation kicks in

Tags: c#, asp.net, cookies

I have been working with a fairly huge database. I want to populate the webcontrols(dropdownlists) of the page during pageload event to give the webpage as much flexibility as possible. For example, I have a dropdownlist ,that user can select, which will be populated from the unique rows of a specific column of a datatable.

Now, i don't want to fire the oracle query each time page load happens because that will slow down the webpage significantly (about 1mins each time). So i started to think of cookies as solution. I soon found out that limitation of cookie size (4kb) is way too small for my purpose. I will need around 10-15kb of size if i really want to store the datarows locally! So I tried to search if there were any way to increase the cookie size limitation to accommodate my needs and I found the possible solution is localstorage.

1. Is there really a way to increase the cookie size limitation?
2. What is the simplest alternative? is it really localstorage? or are there anything else to look into?

details: I am using C#/ASP.NET + ORACLE

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are all storage options for state information in ASP.Net -

- **Cache** - a memory pool stored on the server and shared across users
- **Session** - stored on the server and unique for each user
- **Cookies** - stored on the client and passed with each HTTP request to the server
- **QueryString** - passed as part of the complete URL string
- **Context.Items** - HttpContext and lasts only the lifetime of that request
- **Profile** - stored in a database and maintains information across multiple sessions

> Now, i don't want to fire the oracle query each time page load happens
>   because that will slow down the webpage significantly (about 1mins
>   each time).

You have two options for your scenarion -

- If data shared across users, use **Cache**
- If data is unique for each users, use **Session**

*Ideally, you do not want to store in **ViewState** it will make your page very heavy unless you configure to store ViewState in Sql Server (which is out of the scope of this question).*

### Update:

**localStorage** - Not all browsers can handle localStorage, so make sure you check it first.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   if(window.localStorage)  {
      window.localStorage.SetItem('keyName','valueToUse');
      // OR
      window.localStorage.keyName = 'valueToUse';
   }
</script>
```

***FYI:*** ASP.NET does not offer specific methods for handling local storage; you can only manipulate at client side via javascript.

Comment: yep..true it is. but i was wondering about local storage! i have no prior idea about them and some posts directly refer to them as alternative of cookies so any thought on that?

Comment: oops! only javascript !!!! thats a bummer.. :( i guess cache is my choice then... i was wondering, can i use local text file to store the values? i have absolutely no issues or concern with security. so i was wondering about that.
something like >>>     
if text is present then{pull strings and populate them into the webcontrols}
else {fire sql query to populate the webcontrols;
write back the data into the local textfile}

Comment: Using text file for caching will not be a good choice, because IO call is a lot slower than accessing memory. **Caching** will be a good choice for your case. Microsoft recommends [System.Runtime.Caching](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997357.aspx) if you use .Net 4 or above.

Comment: yep, makes sense. but( pardon me if the question is n00b) can i store the sql output permanently into cache? meaning will the cache be still valid hours after closing the page??? i need an alternative which will allow me the exact privileges of cookie. so that i can store the sql output for a longer time. i am thinking about text file coz even though the IO call will be slower, unless i update it frequently - system memory caching will handle the performance impact. so first request might take a second of two but thereafter the performance wont be such huge issue, at least compared to 1min sql

Comment: `can i store the sql output permanently into cache? meaning will the cache be still valid hours after closing the page???` Yes, you can set expiration time for Cache - few seconds to few days. For your scenario, I'll never consider text file for caching.

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to use cookies.

I had a similar requirement in an application I've been working on. I needed to let a user select a value from ~15,000 choices using an autocomplete input box. I did not want to hit the database each time the component needed to find a value. I decided to use session storage to store all possible values and then feed those values to the autocomplete component. It works great. You could also use local storage.

For my needs, session storage was a better choice because I didn't need to values to persist after the user closed the browser tab. Also, before I store the 15,000 items in session storage, I compress them, using JavaScript compression, to save space. I'm using [lz-string](http://pieroxy.net/blog/pages/lz-string/index.html) for my compression.

Comment: true. i dont want to use cookies anymore either. i will look into local storage coz i am worried about memory impact in case i use session. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to use cookies for this purpose. There's not only the size limitation, but that cookie is sent back and forth with every request to the server, which could potentially reduce responsiveness in your application depending on your server and user's bandwidth.

Another alternative is to use the `Viewstate` which stores the data on the page itself. This doesn't have the space limitation, but it does have the same problem as cookies with the increased request size.

You can also use `Session` which will store the data in memory on the server for each session. This reduces bandwidth requirements, but does take up additional memory space on the server itself, which may not be desirable. Tons of data in memory + tons of sessions could = insufficient memory.

So figure out what your particular tradeoffs are. `Viewstate` is the most similar to your current solution.

To access viewstate or session in your page, just do `Viewstate['KEY']` or `Session['KEY']`

Another thing to note is that the `Session` data is persisted for the entire session and across page loads/redirects/etc. `Viewstate` is ONLY available for that page. If you go to another page, `Viewstate` is discarded.

If you data is the same for all users, then you could also use `Cache`, which stores the data at the Application level instead of session. This still takes up memory space on the server, but will not increase as sessions do (a mere 15k in your case!). You can also specify expiration for the cache (either sliding or absolute), which allows you to automatically free up the memory being used if that resource isn't being accessed for a certain amount of time. Just make sure you always check if the data is in the cache before using it as .NET will discard the information if it expires OR if it just needs to clean up memory for some other purpose.

Comment: totally agree with you for both viewstate and session alternatives. but (might be a noob question) can i permanently store the data using viewstate like cookies? so that i dont have to fire the sql query each time pageload happens? and session whew! the same thing, i am worried about the memory impact. thanks for the clear reply though :)

Comment: Yes you can. You would essentially check "if (Viewstate['DropdownListData'] != null) { /*load from oracle*/ } else { /* use viewstate*/ }. Just remember that viewstate is discarded if you go to another page, which will mean the initial page load will always result in a database call unless you use session. And to reduce the memory requirements, if the data is the same for ALL users, you could use the "Cache", accessed exactly the same as session or viewstate, but persisted at the Application level instead of session, so doesn't have the memory problems.

Comment: well, thats the problem. :( i want the data to persist over time. i know that the contents of the sql query wont change anytime soon. so if i were getting 300datarows initially maybe that will stay same for some time. so cookie was perfect coz i could set the expiry/user could delete and reload/repopulate whenever he would feel.viewstate wont be fit either(since i want the data to persist. so it boils down to cache. i will look into it. how about local storage?what do u say?